# How to change 2D matrix back to 3D array in R

Tags: r, dimensions

I have a 3D array with lon(1:144)(range 0-360 with a step of 2.5), lat(1:29) (20-90 with a step of  2.5) and one variable in time (1:180)(30 years containing 6 months per year).

```
lon <- seq(from = 0, to = 360, by = 2.5) 
lat <- seq(from = 17.5, to = 90, by = 2.5)
time <- c(1:180)
var <- c(28532:31298)
```

I transformed my data to a 2D matrix by multiplying lon*lat:

```
new2Ddata <- matrix(oldmatrix, prod(dim(oldmatrix)[1:2]), dim(oldmatrix)[3])
```

then I calculated svd:

```
svd.result <- svd(new2Ddata)
```

I got svd.result with three components and made a new dataframe using component U [1:4176 (lon*lat), 1:180 (variable)]

```
modes <- as.data.frame(svd.result$u)
```

I have to transform it again to 3D (lon, lat, time, and variable by time). I tried:

```
dim(modes) <- c(144,29,180)
```

I got an error:Error in dim(modes) <- c(144, 29, 180) :
dims [product 751680] do not match the length of object [180]
Any ideas on how to do it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you for adding your data but with the current code we can't recreate your data. Based on your description, I would suggest changing `lat` and `lon` to the following: `lon <- seq(from = 0, to = 360, by = 2.5)` and `lat <- seq(from = 20, to = 90, by = 2.5)` - I would do that for you, however it does not reconcile with your current data (i.e. `lat` seems to start at 17.5 yet your description says the minimum is 20).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry, I am a beginner in programming with R. Is it better now?

Comment: No problem! Just trying to help. Yes this looks great. I would also suggest adding the code that generated `oldmatrix`

Comment: I think the problem lies in this line of code `modes <- as.data.frame(svd.result$u)`. After the conversion, `modes` is no longer of the matrix type needed for your last step. Your code should work if you simply change it to `modes <- svd.result$u`.

Comment: @ekoam thank you! It helped. You can add an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line of code `modes <- as.data.frame(svd.result$u)`. In order to convert the results back to a 3D array, you need `modes` to actually be a matrix rather than a dataframe. Your code should work if you simply change it to `modes <- svd.result$u`.